# how can you migrate from meteor to node/express?

Tags: meteor

I'm thinking of prototying a web and ios app in meteor, if I find there is traction I would like build a native app (non phonegap). I want keep to keep my existing mongo data (user accounts, fb tokens, etc), and build the api in node/express for native ios app. However, I'm not sure how to migrate the user auth to use token based authentication when migrating to node.

P.S my app isn't reactive/realtime and doesn't necessarily require I use ddp.

thanks

Comment: Pick one; just stick with meteor or start with express, honestly. It would probably be a lot less work than creating your app with meteor's paradigms and then trying to switch everything over to a framework that has entirely different principles.

Comment: there doesnt seem to be a good way to create native apps using meteor, which is my only concern, but meteor so much faster get stuff done

Comment: [Meteor has built in support for Cordova.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs)

Comment: its not very efficient for media content, already tried it out, was laggy